# MySQL duplicate query

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division

I am trying to list a query if two types of products are listed in the table. 
This is what I have in my database:

**table1**

```
productID    
productDescription   
productYear
```

**table2**

```
porductID2
productDescription
productID (foreign Key from table1)
```

Table 1 has:

```
01, Ball, 2001
02, Cone, 2002
03, Cube, 2010
```

Table 2 has

```
01, BallBaring, 01
02, LittleBall, 01 
03, BallBaring, 02
04, LittleBall, 02
05, BallBaring, 03
```

I'm trying to display only the results that contain BallBaring AND LittleBall. So when I search the results it only shows the results containing BallBaring AND LittleBall: I have the following search:

```
SELECT table2.productDescription, table1.productDescription, table2.productID2 
FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.productID = table2.productID2 
  AND (table2.productDescription = 'LittleBall' 
       OR table2.productDescription = 'BallBaring');
```

But this brings back all products that have either BallBaring or LittleBall instead of only the ones that have both BallBaring AND LittleBall, if I do AND instead of OR it brings back nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're joining on `productID2` instead of the foreign key (`productID`). This should work:

```
SELECT b.productDescription, a.productDescription, b.productID2
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON b.productID = a.productID
WHERE b.productDescription IN ('LittleBall', 'BallBearing')
```

**Result**

```
| PRODUCTDESCRIPTION | PRODUCTDESCRIPTION  | PRODUCTID2 |
---------------------------------------------------------
|         LittleBall |                Ball |          2 |
|         LittleBall |                Cone |          4 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98416/3)

Comment: I seem to get the all the results that either have LittleBall and BallBaring. So the result of what I want is that the BallBaring must be included in the result where Table1 has both BallBaring and LittleBall from Table2, hope you understand. Thanks for your very quick response.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called `Relational Division` wherein you are searching for a specific value that matches to all conditions.

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  productID
            FROM    table2
            WHERE   productDescription IN ('BallBaring', 'LittleBall')
            GROUP   BY productID
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
        ) b ON a.productID = b.productID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b50b5/1)
- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════╦════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ PRODUCTID ║ PRODUCTDESCRIPTION ║ PRODUCTYEAR ║
╠═══════════╬════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║         1 ║ Ball               ║        2001 ║
║         2 ║ Cone               ║        2002 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```